# 1084: Syntax error: expecting right paren before leftbrace

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

I'm fairly new to action script and I was wondering if any of you guys would be able to solve my problem.

function keyDown (keyEvent:KeyboardEvent):void

{

```
if (keyEvent.keyCode == Keyboard.D
{
    rightPressed = true;
}
else if (keyEvent.keyCode == Keyboard.A
{
    leftPressed = true;
}
else if (keyEvent.keyCode == Keyboard.S
{
    downPressed = true;
}
else if (keyEvent.keyCode == Keyboard.W
{
    upPressed = true;
}
```

}

I thought the code was fine, however whenever I run it I always get the "1084: Syntax error: expecting right parent before leftbrace" error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to close your parenthesis. Like this

```
if (keyEvent.keyCode == Keyboard.D)
```

You have it like this

```
if (keyEvent.keyCode == Keyboard.D
```